# Do you know good SOAP (wsdl) client for Emacs?

Tags: emacsclient

Do you know good SOAP (wsdl) client for Emacs?

I try `C-x C-e` but get error:

```
(soap-load-wsdl-from-url "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL")
```

**progn: Symbol’s function definition is void: soap-load-wsdl-from-url**

Comment: The above works for me: try `M-x load-library RET soap-client`.

Answer (score 1):

There is `soap-client.el` in core Emacs as well as in GNU ELPA.

The commentary at the top of the file says:

```
;;; Commentary:
;;
;; To use the SOAP client, you first need to load the WSDL document for the
;; service you want to access, using `soap-load-wsdl-from-url'.  A WSDL
;; document describes the available operations of the SOAP service, how their
;; parameters and responses are encoded.  To invoke operations, you use the
;; `soap-invoke' method passing it the WSDL, the service name, the operation
;; you wish to invoke and any required parameters.
;;
;; Ideally, the service you want to access will have some documentation about
;; the operations it supports.  If it does not, you can try using
;; `soap-inspect' to browse the WSDL document and see the available operations
;; and their parameters.
;;
```

Comment: Do you have some example how use this client? I try M-x , but can't find command "soap-load-wsdl-from-url"

Comment: It's not a command, so you have to call it like this: `M-: (soap-load-wsdl-from-url "https://path/to/wherever/the/wsdl/file/lives")`. Do `C-h f soap-load-wsdl-from-url`.

Comment: It does not contain *any* commands: it's a pure function library, so you have to write your own program(s) to call its functions. There is an example file `jira2.el` on the [website](https://github.com/alex-hhh/emacs-soap-client) that interfaces with JIRA through SOAP, but [it too is a pure library](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SoapClient) : functions that you can call from your own programs.

Comment: @NickD I'm not need to call functions from my own program. I need to test wsdl file. To send requests (xml format) and see the responses (xml). I'm use fot this the desktop applicaion "SoapUI ver. 5.7.0". But I want to do this by Emacs.